# Azure Logicapps Query Entities not accepting Table Name Parameter

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I built this workflow separately from the others that are in the same location, which are going to be called within the workflow. When I pasted this in the location it should be and while updating the connections it shows me an error with the Query Entities action:

[image: Error Encountered]

> 'TableName' is no longer present in the operation schema. It should be
> removed before the workflow is re-saved.

I don't get this error from the original workflow I mad. I tried deleting the action and adding a new action, the new action doesn't have a field for table name. I also tried to create a new workflow within the folder and it also doesn't have a field for table name.

Comment: Just an update on this, the Logicapp seem to be building and working fine. The only trouble is when opening it in the designer it won't save the workflow because of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing from my end and see that this is working fine after following the below steps.

- I have copied the code view from the source logic app to destination logic app and then saved it without updating the connection. Doing this it actually saved the workflow without any errors

  [image]
- Then I navigated to designer and then configured the connections making sure the table is present for the connections that I am creating with a different name.

  [image]

Following the above steps, I could able to create the workflow without any errors.